# changing the font of textview

Tags: android

I have a ListView, all i want to do is to change the font. i already downloaded my font to the assets/fonts folder.

if i understand right, i supposed to rewrite the adapter..

here is my code:

```
onCreate....


Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/english.ttf");
font1 = Typeface.create(font1, Typeface.BOLD);

TextView customText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ListTextView);
customText.setTypeface(font1);



    HashMap<String,String> contentItem = new HashMap<String,String>()
            {
                {
                put(NAME_FIELD,"dudi");                 
                }
            };              
            content.add(contentItem);



            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            content,  
            R.layout.show_the_list,   
            new String[]{NAME_FIELD},
            new int[]{R.id.ListTextView}   );




            ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            list1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dip"
    android:textColor="@color/White" >
</TextView>
```

if someone can show me the code that i need to add or change, it will be great!
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when you are use `R.id.ListTextView` as a parameter in **SimpleAdapter** then its directly accessed by Adapter to create View so it is every time new not what you have defined in `onCreate()` of Activity,  So either using **Custom TextView** and adding font typeface to it in XML and then use it as argument in **SimpleAdapter** or Write **CustomAdapter** and in `getView()` of it re-define TextView using View inflater and set font typeface in this method..

Comment: thank you for your answer. how exactly i write it in the xml using typeface? i tried several compination but with no success...

Comment: Actually as I seen you as a beginner so its complex you for creating  custom TExtView and adding typeface to in xml. So instead better to write a CustomAdapter and set TypeFace to TextView in getView() of it.